# Storing the output(cout) of a program in a text file using SLURM

Tags: c++, slurm, sbatch

`sbatch -o ${WORKDIR}/logs/submit_${RUN}.out -e ${WORKDIR}/logs/submit_${RUN}.err  -p normal --job-name Rivet_${RUN} --export WORKDIR,RUN,JO,DATASET run_rivet_onnode.sh`

How do I tell slurm that store the output(cout) of my c++ program in .txt file in a directory of my choice

Comment: with -o and -e you should already catch all the output (and error) of your job in the given files.

Comment: Thanks  @MarcusBoden for the reply .I am printing out inside a loop  in the program but they dont appear on the .out file.Any idea how to make the printouts visible?